# Attaching a CSS file to a Java Servlet in Tomcat

Tags: java, html, css, tomcat, servlets

After a lot of looking around on various forums and such, I was not able to find an answer to my question.

I want to attach a stylesheet to my servlet instead of having to use `<style>` tags.

I am using Apache Tomcat 7 in Eclipse and I am manually writing the html code (via a PrintWriter).

I've tried putting the `.css` file in the ROOT of the WebApp. I've tried putting it in the css. Nothing is working.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is some code that I tried.

Attempt 1 (css is in a folder. WebContent/css:

```
    String cssLocation = request.getContextPath() + "/WebContent/css/styles2.css";
    String cssTag = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + cssLocation + "'>";
```

Attempt 2 (css is in the ROOT):

```
    String cssLocation = request.getContextPath() + "/styles2.css";
    String cssTag = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + cssLocation + "'>";
```

Neither of those worked.

EDIT: Here is my directory structure:

```
PROJECT ROOT
    src
        testPackage
            DownloadServlet.java
    WebContent
        css
            styles2.css
        files
        fonts
        js
        META-INF
        WEB-INF
        index.html
```

To explain: I am trying to reference `/WebContent/css/styles2.css` in `DownloadServlet.java`

How I am doing that:

In the method 'doGet', I am initializing a `PrintWriter'. I'm printing out:

```
<html>
<head>
   HERE IS WHERE THE LINK NEEDS TO GO
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Where the text "HERE IS WHERE THE LINK NEEDS TO GO" is, that is where I need the link to the css file. I've tried the methods above, but I had no luck.

Comment: Why not write a JSP file and include the CSS file using `<link>` there?

Comment: Some context might be nice. This really isn't a lot to go on. As far as I can tell, both those should work. Could we get a little more code around it or the page source when you go to the page in the browser?

Comment: This is a simple matter of figuring out what the proper path is relative to your serlvet. Which we can't do since you didn't tell us your folder structure or servlet mapping.

Comment: I made edits to the post. Hopefully that clears it up more. @KamikazeScotsman

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess: Try `String cssTag = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/styles.css'>";`
The browser will look for the css file in the sub-folder of the root directory of the server, which is in your case the WebContent-directory. You usually don't need to call request.getContextPath() when linking resources inside HTML tags.

Comment: But how to include the cssTag string in the Servlet Class.

Answer (score 1):

First you create the css file, suppose `style.css` in the folder name `css` inside the WebContent directory of your project.

Then, you must know the `tomcat server` path where the `.css` file is located.

```
String cssTag="<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css'>"
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head><title>Title Name</title>"+cssTag+"</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
           /*

           Your  code 
           */
    out.println("</body></html>")
```